# Skipping DocuSign login request when using API from application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, docusignapi

My application uses the DocuSign API but in order to request and retrieve a code the DocuSign login form appears when attempting to authenticate. I only have a single user setup in my Sandbox. My plan is for my application to always use the same user to create envelopes and send them.

Here is the call that I am making which is prompting login (how can I avoid the login prompt at all times?):

```
var url = $"https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type={response_type}&scope={scope}&client_id={client_id}&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}";
return Redirect(url);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information you've provided indicates you're probably using an OAuth Code Grant flow.

Part of this flow requires the user you're creating the token for enter their username / password. If you don't want this to happen, and while it's not the most recommended method, you could use a JWT (JSON Web Token) flow instead.

https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/oauth2-jsonwebtoken

You'll be required to provide consent for the user you're sending as initially, but once you've provided said consent you'll be able to generate tokens for them without entering a username / password. This remains the case unless consent is revoked or the username / password for the user changes.

Please see https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/obtaining-consent for additional information.